# Render html-content from remote html-file (AWS bucket) into django-template

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-views, django-templates

I am running a django app and I am building a newsletter. I have a newsletter-model that has a file-field where I attach a html-document (which is the content of the newsletter). This file gets automatically uploaded to an AWS bucket.

I also want to display the newsletter on my website. So I am trying to find a solution how I could render the HTML-content from the HTML-file as my django-template.

My model:

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    attachment = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, storage=MediaStoragePrivate())
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I tried various things:

1. I tried getting the attachments content, saving it into a variable and rendering it to the template

```
def list_newsletter(request):
    newsletter = Newsletter.objects.last()
    attachment = self.attachment.read().decode("utf-8")
  
    return render(
        request, "newsletter_list.html", {"newsletter": attachment}
    )
```

This gives me the text but with the `html`-tags included (`<h1> ladadilada </h1>`), but I want the interpreted html not raw text.

2. I tried this with beautiful soup

```
 htmltxt = Newsletter.objects.last().attachment
 soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltxt, 'html.parser')
```

But also this prints the html-tags. I can print it with .text, but this does not interpret the html-tages but just prints raw text.

3. Tried rendering the URL but it gives me the URL.

Is it even possible what I am trying to do? It would be quite handy to do this, otherwise I would somehow save each html-page locally again in my app.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: what do you mean by interpreted html and not raw text

Comment: I mean for example that when the html file has <strong>this is bold</strong> tags, that "this is bold" is actually rendered in bold...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Django will escape your string to render exact text.

If you want to show it as HTML you can turn off [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) or use [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template tag

Comment: Thank you so much iklinac! Works like a charm!